# Date picker using jquery for dob year validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using date picker from Jquery. Where currently I facing one problem By default the calendar will show till 2100 years but if the user select any feature date or current date the system should not accept. The system should accept the date minimum 10 year previous from todays date.

I am bit confused how to do I tried with min year &  max year but If i gave year range as 1900 to 2015 calendar was showing till 2015 sep only but i want to show till 2100

Here is the jsbin [Link](http://jsbin.com/jituse/edit?html,js,output)

Guys kindly help me

Here is the Jquery code

```
 $("#txt_dob").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,

    //showButtonPanel: true,
    yearRange: '-115:+10',
    beforeShow: function () {
        setTimeout(function (){
        $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', 99999999999999);

        }, 0);
    },

}).on('change', function() {
    if($('#txt_dob').valid()){
        $('#txt_dob').removeClass('errRed');
    }
    // triggers the validation test on change

});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: use `maxDate` option to set a maximum date that user can select . [Docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate)

Comment: I checked that boss it was not working

Comment: it is working. check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/e9aqL8ja/3/).just took your code to jsfiddle and put maxDate option nothing else i did

Answer (score 2):

My solution would be to create a Date object:
`var date = new Date(); // current date`
Then substract 10 years:
`date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() - 10)`
Then affect this date to be the maximum date of your date picker

```
$("#txt_dob").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
    maxDate: date,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
});
```

Comment: @cracker thanks for the answer but my question was the user want to see the calendar till 2100 but field should accept only 10 years from today

Comment: Then change maxDate to minDate

Comment: @Mahadevan, I have edite it answered by some other guy

Comment: @Ghassen My calendar has to show from 1900 - 2100 but system should accept only minimum 10 year previous from todays date

Comment: in your onChange function add this code var pattern = /(\d{2})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{4})/; var currentDate = new Date(); var selectedDate = new Date($(this).val().replace(pattern,'$3-$1-$2')); Then compare between selectedDate and currentDate, the difference must be less or equal than 10 years

Answer (score 1):

Use the `maxDate` property of the date picker as follows:

```
maxDate: '-10Y'
```